# Adjust a complete shapefile of multiple points on ArcMap taking other few as reference?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, point, spatial-adjustment

I received a shapefile with georeferenced trees, but they didn't use a GPS to get the coordinates (not sure how they did it, some traditional stuff maybe?). So, the position doesn't match exactly on the field. I need to correct this for planning some plots. I mapped myself some of the trees on the field and compared to the first shapefile, they seem to have a semi-consistent displacement at NE and the distance varies between 70-80 m.

Is there some way to correct this? I can afford accuracy to 10 m

If so, how many trees would be needed to map on the field for reference? The first shapefile has approx. 3000 points

Comment: I would contact your source for more information. Even if GPS wasn't used and it was a Total Station survey or something, it sounds like there might be a coordinate system issue in the data - either the wrong CRS is specified, wrong/no transformation specified, etc. Depending on where you are, that sounds like it could be NAD27 vs NAD83 datum conflicts. You can certainly do a spatial adjustment and warp the points to fit your mapping, but that may or may not be any more accurate than the data you were given - especially if your mapping was with a consumer GPS unit.

Comment: GPS is very inaccurate in trees.  How are you determining location in the field to determine that the trees aren't accurately mapped?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way to correct this?

As you've correctly identified, using spatial adjustment in ArcMap will help adjust the points in your shapefile.

From the document [About spatial adjustment](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment.htm)

1. Start ArcMap.
2. Create a new map or open an existing one.
3. Add the data you want to edit to your map.
4. Add the Editor toolbar to ArcMap.
5. Add the Spatial Adjustment toolbar to ArcMap.
6. Start your edit session.
7. Choose the input data for the adjustment.
8. Choose a spatial adjustment method.
9. Create displacement links.
10. Perform the adjustment.
11. Stop your edit session and save your edits.

> If so, how many trees would be needed to map on the field for
>   reference? The first shape file has aprox 3000 points

Depending on the type of transformation used to spatially adjust, the number of trees to be mapped (displacement links) will be different. It's usually around 2 to 4. The [About spatial adjustment transformations](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/editing-existing-features/about-spatial-adjustment-transformations.htm) details this information. While mapping the points on field, it's best to select trees that span across the extent of the area being worked on for increased accuracy. Generally, the more links you place for a transformation, the more accurate it will be. You can check the accuracy of the transformation by viewing the RMS errors in the link table.